# Root partition full after 2 hours of usage

Tags: ubuntu, partition, storage, root-filesystem, pop-os

I recently received a message indicating space was running low in my root partition, so I decided to increase my partition's size from 9GB to 30GB (just to be sure) I wouldn't have to deal with this in the future when I'm busy in the future. I did this maybe 2 hours ago, but I just received this message again? It seems like my root partition is now full of 27 GB, is there a chance programs or files are being storef in my root partition?

Here is the output of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   529M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0 540.3G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  29.1G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0 360.5G  0 part /home
```

Output for `du -h --max-depth 1 /var`

```
4.0K    /var/mail
4.0K    /var/opt
18G     /var/lib
9.8M    /var/spool
55M     /var/crash
8.0K    /var/lock
90M     /var/cache
905M    /var/log
76K     /var/tmp
4.0K    /var/local
132K    /var/backups
19G     /var
```

**Update:** Very recently I installed docker for running oracle db, so I though maybe this could be a cause. In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853571/why-is-docker-image-eating-up-my-disk-space-that-is-not-used-by-docker), this command is recommended for removing all containers and images and I freed up 13gb in space.

I was using this container just for playing around, since I indeed up installing 11g in my windows partition.

Output for `du -x / | sort -n | tail -30`

```
318900  /usr/share/libreoffice/help
326748  /usr/lib/libreoffice
332656  /usr/share/libreoffice
341964  /usr/share/fonts/opentype
412112  /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
412124  /usr/lib/jvm
480108  /usr/share/fonts
491740  /usr/bin
668084  /usr/lib/firmware
922872  /var/log/journal/3699a9056d9109ba5307595660a9fe08
922876  /var/log/journal
937232  /var/log
956460  /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data/u02/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/orclpdb1
1081484 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
1110068 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data/u02/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/pdbseed
2668860 /usr/share
3526180 /usr/lib
3777544 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data/u02/app/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB
3777548 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data/u02/app/oracle/oradata
3778008 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data/u02/app/oracle
3778012 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data/u02/app
3778016 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data/u02
3814936 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e/_data
3814940 /var/lib/docker/volumes/98c155107c69aa57a69cc71514d4976fb484bb5a6467d6c6ae61ac67092b920e
3814968 /var/lib/docker/volumes
3815324 /var/lib/docker
4250432 /var/lib
5428724 /var
7058496 /usr
12854996    /
```

Comment: almost all programs will be on the root fs, in /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, etc.  same for shared libraries (e.g. /lib and /usr/lib), man pages, documentation, log files, etc unless you created separate partitions for them.   Ubuntu also downloads its apt lists and packages to /var/lib/apt/lists and /var/cache/apt/archives.  The latter can take a lot of space if you don't clear it out regularly with `apt clean`.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo du -x / | sort -n | tail -30` as an edit to your question, please. `df --max-depth 1 /var` barely fits your issue.

Comment: `/var/lib/docker` has eaten your space. `/var/log/journal` is unusually large. `/usr/share/fonts` - close to 500MB of fonts? Windows 10 has less than that :-)

Answer (score 1):

The main directory to look at is /var which is for everything writable by normal applications.  There are also /run and /tmp but these are often a RAM disk on many distributions.

You can use

```
df --max-depth 1 /var
```

to investigate which one.  **do not** delete things before you know what they are.

When systems blow through their storage like you are describing it's often caused by something stuck spinning round on a condition writing a log file, the log file can end up several GB.  So /var/log is quite likely.

Occasionally it can also be caused by a a process gone haywire writing to /var/cache /var/tmp or /var/lib.

Comment: I recently installed docker and played around with some Virtual Machines